# How to get friends without cats from MySQL?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a plain text as it is list of friends ID's that is not stored in the database, cause I have it in PHP like a string:

```
7375,8983429,478243
```

And I have a table users and a table cats.

Table users has a column ID and NAME and table cats has a column ID, NAME, and USER_ID.

I would like to get these friends of mine that don't have cats. How to do so?

Comment: @tomasz: perhaps you might consider formulating your question more carefully, instead of responding with a rude "beep wrong" when your question is misunderstood.

Comment: @Pontus Gagge It's formulated ok. And 9muses answer proves it to be precise enought. So let it go.

Comment: "it is list of friends ID's that is not stored in the database": so then create a table, insert a row for each item in the list, join tables in the usual way.

Comment: @tomasz: sorry for my mistake. Apparently, you're fine with sounding a bit rude, and this time, you even got help. No skin off my nose.

Comment: @onedaywhen it's not a solution.

Comment: @Pontus Gagge Yeah maybe you are right. it was a little rude, just sometimes it irritates that people don't read whole question. but you are everyone here help voluntarely and it counts. thanks for remaider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN cats ON cats.USER_ID=users.ID WHERE cats.ID IS NULL
```

To get only specific friends add this to the end of the SQL

```
AND users.ID IN (7375,8983429,478243)
```